# No ROS_WARN messages in ros log file

Tags: logging, ros-noetic

I ported my project to Noetic coming from Kinetic. But now all my ROSWARN are not in the logfile when I launch it with output log. When I launch it with output screen, all ROSWARNs are landing in screen. This only happens with ROS C++ nodes. My Python ROS nodes are showing roswarn in the log file.

With my old Kinetic Setup only ROSERROR was not in the log file.

Does someone has any idea how to fix that.